# most efficient way in Pandas to transform a trade dataset into a long format?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like

```
tradeid  buyer   seller   quantity
1        John    Mark     10
2        Frank   John     5
3        John    Jesse    4
```

where basically each line corresponds to a trade between a buyer and a seller. For instance, in row one we see that John (the buyer) bought a quantity of 10 of goods from Mark (the seller).

I would like to transform the dataset in a way where each row corresponds instead to a trader, and where I have the corresponding total quantity bought or sold by this trader. That is

`output`

```
trader  totalbuy  totalsell   
John    14        5
Frank   5         0    
Jesse   0         4
Mark    0         10
```

I am using the last version of pandas, and the data is large. What would be the most efficient way to do the transformation above?

Many thanks!!

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

datastring = StringIO("""\
tradeid  buyer   seller   quantity
1        John    Mark     10
2        Frank   John     5
3        John    Jesse    4
""")

df = pd.read_table(datastring, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a couple of `groupby`-`sum` followed by a horizontal `concat`:

```
>>> >>> pd.concat(
    [df.quantity.groupby(df.buyer).sum()\
        .reset_index().set_index('buyer').rename(columns={'quantity': 'totalBuy'}),
    df.quantity.groupby(df.seller).sum()\
            .reset_index().set_index('seller').rename(columns={'quantity': 'totalSell'})],
    axis=1).fillna(0)
    totalBuy    totalSell
Frank   5   0
Jesse   0   4
John    14  5
Mark    0   10
```

Comment: @Noobie You're welcome. It's a very powerful library.

Comment: btw why are you resetting and setting index after the groupby? doesnt groupby automatically creates an index?

Comment: @Noobie This type of `groupby` creates a `Series`; the `reset_index` transforms it into a `DataFrame`, and the `set_index` then makes one of the columns the index.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['quantity'], value_vars=['buyer', 'seller'],
         value_name='trader', var_name='tradetype')
 .groupby(['tradetype', 'trader'])
 .sum()
 .unstack(level=0)
 .fillna(0)
 .quantity
 .rename(columns={'buyer': 'totalbuy', 'seller': 'totalsell'})
)

tradetype  totalbuy  totalsell
trader                        
Frank             5          0
Jesse             0          4
John             14          5
Mark              0         10
```

Comment: thanks! i never really understood what is `melt` for. That is, to which extent it does stuff I cannot do with `pivot` or `groupby`